# How to make beamer, tikzmark and tabularray compatible?

Tags: beamer, tabularray, tikzmark

### **Problem Description**

`beamer` and `tikzmark` works correctly inside a `matrix` environment. But when they are used within a `tblr` environment, a large gap occurs. How can this be fixed? The use of `tikzmarknode` is preferred.

[image]

### **MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode works for matrix}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
1 & \tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
\onslide<2->{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode doesn't work for tblr and one layer}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 & \tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode doesn't work for tblr and multiple layers}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 & \tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}
\only<2->{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{a second example}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 & \tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {important};
\draw[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> Don't forget the fraction
\item<3-> It's $\frac{1}{2}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So ... this is complicated ...

I know next to nothing about `tabularray`, but from what I have found out then it does a *lot* of measuring stuff to figure out how to lay out the cells in the tables. In my experiments, each cell got typeset *at least* five times, and it was actually the *fourth* version that is actually rendered.  So what that means is that the node in `\tikzmarknode` is defined five times (at least - it gets more complicated when you throw maths into the mix because then `\tikzmarknode` does some internal stuff with `\mathchoice` to match the outer math mode).

Over the years, I've built in a sophisticated system for `\tikzmark` to ensure that the point remembered on the page is actually the point that appears on the page, so if a `\tikzmark` is processed in a box that is subsequently discarded then the resulting `\tikzmark` is discarded.  One part of this is relevant to `beamer` since if a `\tikzmark` is on a frame with multiple slides then the actual mark may move between slides depending on the other frame contents but the name stays the same.  The method for fixing this is to silently append the beamer slide number to each `\tikzmark` - both when it is defined and when it is used.  This ensures that the `\tikzmark` being used is the same as that being defined.

Now we return to the `\tikzmarknode`. This suffers the same problem - by having multiple slides you are reusing the same node name on separate slides. Normally, this isn't a problem since defining a node overwrites previous definitions meaning that the current definition of a node is always the most recent one (this is different to the underlying `\tikzmark` since that has to work via the `aux` file meaning that the last `\tikzmark` with a given name is the one in use throughout the entire document).  However, because `tabularray` defines and throws away its cells multiple times, the node definitions get tangled up.  In particular, it would appear that at a crucial stage, the node definition in use on the second slide is actually one from the first slide. What is crucial is that this is used in setting the `baseline` of the `\tikzmarknode` and this affects the height of the cell.

So there are two options, one simple and one a little more complicated.  I'm presenting them both in part so that I remember that they both exist because I can envision scenarios later on where the simple one isn't suitable.

The simple solution is to emulate the slide-fix from `\tikzmark` on `\tikzmarknode`.  This is to silently append the slide number to node names:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  name suffix=-\the\beamer@slideinframe
}
\makeatother
```

(this might need to be `name suffix/.append=\the\beamer@slideinframe` if you are using other `name suffix`s in your document.)

This could be done just on `\tikzmarknode`s by using the `every tikzmarknode picture` style.

The more sophisticated method disables the `baseline` setting for `\tikzmarknode`s that aren't rendered.  For this, we need to define a new key that tests whether the `\tikzmarknode` is actually rendered and allows us to execute different styles depending on whether or not it is.

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  if picture is remembered/.code 2 args={
    \ifpgfrememberpicturepositiononpage
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@\pgfpictureid}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
    }%
    \fi
  },
  every tikzmarknode picture/.style={
    if picture is remembered={
    }{
      baseline=default
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654140/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  if picture is remembered/.code 2 args={
    \ifpgfrememberpicturepositiononpage
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@\pgfpictureid}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#1}%
    }%
    \fi
  },
  every tikzmarknode picture/.style={
    if picture is remembered={
    }{
      baseline=default
    }
  },
%  name suffix=-\the\beamer@slideinframe
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode doesn't work for tblr}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 & \tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}
\only<2->{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, enclosing the entire `tikzpicture` in the `\only` does lead to a very small jump in the overall location of the `tblr` environment on the page.  This is because even with `overlay`, the `tikzpicture` does form a box which, even though empty, can shift things slightly.  A simple fix is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node<2-> (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw<2->[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this ensures that the box is always there.

[image: showing a working tikzmarknode in beamer with tabularray]

(Page number included to show that this is the *second* slide)

Comment: This is a comprehensive answer beyond my knowledge. I did some tests and it seems to me the best general fix (the sophisticated one) for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

To completly avoid the problem, you can use `\tikzmark` instead of `\tikzmarknode`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode doesn't work for tblr}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 &  \frac{1}{2}\tikzmark{A} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node<2-> (B) at ($(pic cs:A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw<2->[->,red] (pic cs:A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you for some reason need the `\tikzmarknode`, you can work around the problem by only using the `\tikzmarknode` on the second overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{tikzmarknode doesn't work for tblr}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tblr}{cells = {mode = imath}}
1 & \alt<2>{\tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2}} \\
3 & 4
\end{tblr}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node<2> (B) at ($(A) + (45:2)$) {fraction!};
\draw<2>[->,red] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, so this is the reason? Interesting. I tried different things but not this. A bit strange though

Comment: @JasperHabicht Part of the reason. There is something going on with the height measurement...

Comment: @samcarter I've updated my answer and you can see that `\alt<>` is not the best general solution. Although, I like your first idea of using `\smash` as workaround. Combine it with `\vphantom`? Something like `\smash{\tikzmarknode{A}{\frac{1}{2}}}\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}`